# Outline of pixels after detecting object (without convex hull)

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, direct2d

The idea is to use [grabcut](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) (OpenCV) to detect the image inside a rectangle and create a geometry with Direct2D.

My test image is this:

[image]

After performing the grab cut, resulting in this image:

[image]

the idea is to outline it. I can use an [opacity brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-brushes-overview) to exclude it from the background but I want to use a geometric brush in order to be able to append/widen/combine geometries on it like all other selections in my editor (polygon, lasso, rectangle, etc).

If I apply the convex hull algorithm to the points, I get this:

[image]

Which of course is not desired for my case. How do I outline the image?

After getting the image from the grabcut, I keep the points based on luminance:

```
DWORD* pixels = ...
    for (UINT y = 0; y < he; y++)
    {
        for (UINT x = 0; x < wi; x++)
        {
            DWORD& col = pixels[y * wi + x];
            auto lumthis = lum(col);
            if (lumthis > Lum_Threshold)
            {
                points.push_back({x,y});
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I sort the points on Y and X:

```
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [](D2D1_POINT_2F p1, D2D1_POINT_2F p2) -> bool
        {
            if (p1.y < p2.y)
                return true;
            if ((int)p1.y == (int)p2.y && p1.x < p2.x)
                return true;
            return false;
        });
```

Then, for each line (traversing the above point array from top Y to bototm Y) I create "groups" for each line:

```
    struct SECTION
    {
        float left = 0, right = 0;
    };
    auto findgaps = [](D2D1_POINT_2F* p,size_t n) -> std::vector<SECTION>
    {
        std::vector<SECTION> j;
        SECTION* jj = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                SECTION jp;
                jp.left = p[i].x;
                jp.right = p[i].x;
                j.push_back(jp);
                jj = &j[j.size() - 1];
                continue;
            }
            if ((p[i].x - jj->right) < 1.5f)
            {
                jj->right = p[i].x;
            }
            else
            {
                SECTION jp;
                jp.left = p[i].x;
                jp.right = p[i].x;
                j.push_back(jp);
                jj = &j[j.size() - 1];
            }

        }

        return j;
    };
```

I'm stuck at this point. I know that from an arbitrary set of points many polygons are possible, but in my case the points have defined what's "left" and what's "right". How would I proceed from here?

Comment: Your region is also non-single linked (and theorecally may be non-single bound), if your intent is combine selections. From what I know, editor like that used to scan raster line by line  in order to build region geometry, an advantage of discrete space that the picture is. My knowledge is hugely outdated about that (~20 years) though. They likely take advantage of OpenGL\OpenCL

Comment: If I understand correctly then this answer might help you
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856650/how-to-use-opencv-contours-to-describe-line-points-in-a-unidirectional-way/60913155#60913155)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the solution is [OpenCV contours](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d05/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_contours.html). Working example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html).