# How to find valleys and intersections in a distance field?

Tags: python, geometry, distance, voronoi, delaunay

I have a 2d array representing height. It contains peaks, and then a linear gradient in between the peaks.

I am generating the array myself, based on the positions of the peaks. The gradient is simply the distance to the nearest peak. So the resolution of the actual array is higher than that of the posted images.

(Originally I only posted white/blue images, I've left the rest of them as is)

Original image (visualisation of the array):
[image]

I would like to find the valleys and their intersections, as a set of line segments, visualised as below.

[image]

I'm aware of various approaches to finding the minima, but no way to explicitly figuring out the exact intersections and the line segments in between them.

I've been working on this for a large number of hours but haven't got anywhere. I've tried things like below (arr is the array):

```
minima = (arr != scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter(arr, size=10, mode='constant', cval=0.0))
modified_arr = np.where(minima, arr, 1500)
```

and I've also tried iterating explicitly over rows/columns separately, with similar code to above. Both of these approaches are 'spotty', they identify a lot of the valleys when plotted, but they're not fully connected line segments.

Crucially, what I haven't worked out how to do is actually define where the intersections are and the line segments in between them formed by the valleys. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

I'd like to also know the actual depth value of the intersection points as well if possible.

Mathematically, I know that the intersections are defined by points which are an equal distance from three peaks, and the valleys are defined by points which are an equal distance from two peaks.

**TL;DR** - I want to find the intersections/valleys as a set of line segments, can anyone help?

**Update**
I've got part of the way. It's a bit rough, but the below does find all the intersections and valleys, except there are extra points found. This is because the only way I found which would consistently discover all the intersections/valleys was to allow a margin. Also, there's an extra intersection and valley in the top left, I forgot to indicate those in the original picture, there is actually a second peak directly beside another one.`
I had to play around with the 'magic numbers' at the top to find a happy point where all the intersections/valleys are found but not too many points are included.

My current idea for moving forwards is to apply K-means to the intersections to find the centroids of those points. For the valleys I'm not so sure, possibly look at defining the angles that nearby valley points are at in relation to intersections, and then finding which intersection lies on the same angle. I also thought of limiting the discovered valley points to those within a certain distance of an intersection, which would possibly make K-means appropriate for those as well.

If anyone has anything to add I'd appreciate it. Otherwise I'll post further results when I get there.

```
max_int_diff = 0.85  # max intersection difference
max_valley_diff = 0.45  # max valley difference
max_edge_dist = 2  # max distance from edge of graph
intersections = []
valleys = []
for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[0]):
        dists = [(hypot((i - node.x), (j - node.y)), node) for node in peaks.values()]
        closest = sorted(dists, key=lambda _x: _x[0])
        # intersections
        diff_1_2 = abs(closest[0][0] - closest[1][0])
        diff_1_3 = abs(closest[0][0] - closest[2][0])
        diff_2_3 = abs(closest[1][0] - closest[2][0])
        if diff_1_3 <= max_int_diff and diff_2_3 <= max_int_diff and diff_1_2 <= max_int_diff:
            intersections.append((i, j))
        # edge of graph valleys bound the graph, so they are counted as intersections
        elif diff_1_2 <= max_valley_diff \
                and (i <= max_edge_dist or i >= array_size - max_edge_dist
                        or j <= max_edge_dist or j >= array_size - max_edge_dist):
            intersections.append((i, j))
        # valleys
        elif diff_1_2 <= max_valley_diff:
            valleys.append((i, j))
```

[image]

**Update 2**
I've now managed to use `ndimage.minimum_filter` to accurately find the majority of the valley points :) I combined individual axis processing to get the below result. Still missing some points though. Any thoughts on how I can improve this would be appreciated. I've tried changing the size up/down but this is the best result I can get.
My current idea to find the missing points is to add two more filters that look at the two 45 degree axes, as it seems to be the angle of the valleys which is affecting it.

```
# using scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter
minima_0 = (arr != minimum_filter(arr, axes=0, size=10, mode='constant', cval=20.0))
minima_1 = (arr != minimum_filter(arr, axes=1, size=10, mode='constant', cval=20.0))
# return a masked arr, where minima have been replaced with a value
arr_0 = np.where(minima_0, arr, 50)
arr_1 = np.where(minima_1, arr, 50)
mg = arr_0 + arr_1
```

[image]

**Update 2**
I've posted an answer. The real issue was my own lack of knowledge in mathematics, due to having never studied it formally beyond high school. Initially I was overcomplicating it by presenting it as an image processing problem, even though my actual data was just an array of points.

Hopefully this all might help someone else!

Comment: You might consider adding the `image-processing` tag to attract some good minds. You might also add your input image without borders/axes/annotations so folk can work on the actual data - probably without colour too if your colour has been added via a palette. It looks like Voronoi processing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MarkSetchell, I hadn't thought of it as image-processing. I'll add the original image as well. I've used matplotlib to plot the array with colour, I can do a grayscale one with no axis :)

Comment: you might also want to post the list of peak coordinates ([mre]). you seem to have your peaks already and just generated the distance field from them.  -- keywords: voronoi, delaunay. look them up, might solve your problem in a way that doesn't involve a distance field.

Comment: I'll post the peak coordinates. And yes, thanks both @ChristophRackwitz and MarkSetchell, you are right about the Voronoi. I've looked it up and that is exactly what I want. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the end was indeed Voronoi processing, as suggested by both @MarkSetchell and @ChristophRackwitz. Thanks to both of you for your comments, I wouldn't have found the answer without your help!

Essentially, what I've been looking for is called the [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Refer to this link for helpful examples using `Scipy`:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/spatial.html#voronoi-diagrams
I based some of my own code from examples on that page, particularly the infinite edges which were tricky.

As mentioned, I already have the coordinates of the peak points. From there it's very simple to generate the Voronoi Diagram:

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

points = np.array([[612, 578], [487, 958], [324, 972], [370, 886], [884, 435], [64, 557]])
vor = Voronoi(points)
```

The Voronoi object can then be used to get the intersections and edges, noting that bounded edges and infinite edges are treated differently.

```
def voronoi_intersections(voronoi):
    """Returns the Voronoi intersections. This does not include the imaginary 'end' points of the unbounded edges."""
    return list(voronoi.vertices)

def voronoi_bounded_edges(voronoi):
    """Returns all bounded Voronoi edges from the Voronoi Diagram as indices into the points array."""
    arr = np.array(voronoi.ridge_vertices)
    mask = np.all(arr >= 0, axis=1)
    masked = arr[mask]
    return masked

def voronoi_all_edges(voronoi, points):
    """Gets all Voronoi edges from the Voronoi Diagram as indices into the points array, including infinite edges.
    See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/spatial.html#voronoi-diagrams:~:text=The%20ridges%20extending%20to%20infinity%20require%20a%20bit%20more%20care%3A
    """

    all_voronoi_vertices = voronoi_intersections(voronoi)  # will add the interpolated 'far' points to this
    all_voronoi_edges = list(voronoi_bounded_edges(voronoi))  # will add the infinite edges to this

    center = points.mean(axis=0)
    for pointidx, simplex in zip(voronoi.ridge_points, voronoi.ridge_vertices):
        simplex = np.asarray(simplex)
        if np.any(simplex < 0):
            i = simplex[simplex >= 0][0]  # finite end Voronoi vertex
            t = points[pointidx[1]] - points[pointidx[0]]  # tangent
            t = t / np.linalg.norm(t)
            n = np.array([-t[1], t[0]])  # normal
            midpoint = points[pointidx].mean(axis=0)
            # In the below I've multiplied the vector 10x to lengthen the returned edge well outside the bounds
            # of the instance. I believe 10x is enough. This is a bit hacky, but I couldn't work out why it wasn't
            # matching the source code plotting output.
            far_point = voronoi.vertices[i] + 10 * np.sign(np.dot(midpoint - center, n)) * n * 100

            all_voronoi_vertices.append(far_point)
            all_voronoi_edges.append(np.array([i, len(all_voronoi_vertices) - 1]))
```

And here's the plot of the peaks and the edges, not including the intersections:
[image: example plot of peaks and voronoi edges]

Answer (score -1):

If you treat this as an image processing problem, I would look into the following algorithms:

Find the valleys first by using a ridge detector:
see https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_ridge_filter.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-ridge-filter-py

[image: Ridge detection]

Next use a simple treshold to get a binary mask. Afterwards use skeletonize-functions to get the underlying net.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html

[image: Skeleton]

The junctions are a little trickier:
You could check each pixel in the skeleton for the number of adjacent pixels. A junction is located where there are more than 2 neighbors:

[Finding intersections of a skeletonised image in python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705405/finding-intersections-of-a-skeletonised-image-in-python-opencv)

Alternatively, you could try a hit and miss strategy to find the intersections:

https://answers.opencv.org/question/103162/detection-of-contours-intersections/

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_hit_or_miss.html

If you need the lines as well, you could try probabilistic hough lines.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.probabilistic_hough_line

You have to play around with the parameters a bit:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this very much, and your answer may help someone else, but in this case both of the original commenters were correct in their assessment that this required Voronoi processing. I'll be posting an answer with the detail. Unfortunately I've had life-stuff getting in the way for a few weeks.